# How to add play again option for a hangman in python?

Tags: python, function

I have done these steps of the hangman:

Write a function hangman() which allows you to play hangman and returns the word
‘victory’ or ‘defeat’ depending on the result.
In this function:

1. randomly draw a word then called mystery_word
2. define word_found as a list of characters (and not as a
   character string) of the length of the word to guess
3. ask the player for a letter
4. call a function word_update(word_mystery, word_found, l)
   written outside of hangman() which updates found_word if the letter l
   is contained in the mystery word and which returns a boolean indicating whether
   the letter is in mystery_word
5. display the progress of word_found, display the hangman if the word has not
   not found after the number of trials permitted by the drawings or
   complete the game if all the letters of the word have been found.

I need to do this improvement: ***
but make sure that the hangman() function returns "victory" or "defeat" whether the use wins or loses:

*Outside of the hangman() function, offer the player to play again
after a game and display at the end the percentage of victories and that of
defeats.

```
def hangmandrawing(index):
        tab = ['''

       +---+
       |   |
           |
           |
           |
           |
     =========''', '''
    
       +---+
       |   |
       O   |
           |
           |
           |
    =========''', '''
 
       +---+
       |   |
       O   |
       |   |
           |
           |
     =========''', '''
    
       +---+
       |   |
       O   |
      /|   |
           |
           |
     =========''', '''
  
       +---+
       |   |
       O   |
      /|\  |
           |
           |
     =========''', '''
  
       +---+
       |   |
       O   |
      /|\  |
      /    |
           |
     =========''', '''
 
       +---+
       O   |
      /|\  |
      / \  |
           |
     =========''']
        
        return tab[index]
    
import random

words = ["critic","modest","crystal","vision","block"]

def hangman():
    mystery_word = random.choice(words) 
    mystery_word = "hey"
    word_found = list(mystery_word) 
    print("This is the state of the hangman : \n " ,hangmandrawing(0), " \n") 
    print(f"The mystery word is : {len(mystery_word) * ' _' } and has {len(mystery_word)} letters. \n ")
    lives = 6 
    drawing_number = 1
    hangman.letters = [] 
    while (''.join(word_found)) != mystery_word or lives > 0:
        l = input("Enter a letter : ").lower() 
        if len(l) > 1 or len(l) == 0: 
            print("You have to enter 1 letter.\n")
            continue
        elif l in hangman.letters: 
            print("You have already entered this letter.\n")
            continue  
        hangman.letters.append(l)
        word_update(mystery_word, word_found, l)
        print(f"\n{word_update.answer}")
        if l in mystery_word: 
            times_l = (mystery_word).count(l) 
            print(f"Well done! The letter you have entered is {times_l} time in the word. ")
            print(f"The word is now : {''.join(word_found)}\n")
        elif l not in mystery_word:
            lives -= 1 
            print(f"The letter you have entered is not in the word, you now have {lives} lives. \n")
            print("This is the state of the hangman : " ,hangmandrawing(drawing_number), "\n") 
            print(f"The word is still : {''.join(word_found)}\n")
            drawing_number += 1
        if (''.join(word_found)).replace(" ", "") == mystery_word: 
            print("Well done! You have foudn the word and won the game.\n")
            return "victory"
        elif lives == 0: 
            print("Unlucky, you have no more lives and you have lost.")
            print(f"The word was {mystery_word}. \n")
            return "defeat"
        print(f"You have used the letters : ({', '.join(sorted(hangman.letters))})\n") 
          
def word_update(mystery_word, word_found, l):
    for i in range(len(mystery_word)):
        if list(mystery_word)[i] in hangman.letters:
            word_found[i] = " " + list(mystery_word)[i] 
        else:
            word_found[i] = " _"
    if l in mystery_word:
        word_update.answer = True
        return word_found, word_update.answer
    elif l not in mystery_word:
        word_update.answer = False
        return word_found, word_update.answer
    
#This is my code and so i need help to :

Outside of the hangman() function, offer the player to play again
after a game and display at the end the percentage of victories and that of
defeats.(but make sure that the hangman() function returns "victory" or "defeat" like in my code uptop)
```

Answer (score 0):

so you are able to make a while loop just after the end.

```
# Your code here
while True:
   hangman()
```

Further if you want to keep track of wins and losses, make 2 variables, win and loss with each time if you won inside the while loop do win++ or loss++ to add 1 to their value. You are also able to print them if you want.